# Avoid animation of UITableViewCell contents, when using AutoLayout and animating size of UITableView

Tags: uitableview, animation, ios8, autolayout

Initially I have a UITableView which takes up only a small part of the screen, using AutoLayout constraints. The UITableViewCells are laid out nicely - they are very basic with just an orange left aligned label and a black right aligned label.

Now, if I swipe up on the UITableView, it animates (the AutoLayout constraints), to take up a larger part of the screen, while reloading the table and bringing additional UITableViewCells into the scene.

My problem is, that the layout of the new UITableViewCells is animated along with the resizing of the UITableView. The black right label occurs right after the orange label, and animates to the right. In the end, everything is aligned as expected, only I can't figure out why the black right labels isn't simply positioned to the very right as soon as the cell appears on screen, but instead is animated into position.

Is there a way to tell the UITableViewCell to layout it's contents right away with respect to the width of the UITableView and the specified AutoLayout constraints, and thus bypassing the animation of the UITableViewCell contents?

My code for creating the UITableViewCell looks like this:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.textLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        self.textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.textLabel];

        self.amountLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        self.amountLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.amountLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        self.amountLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.amountLabel];


        NSDictionary *views = @{@"textLabel": self.textLabel, @"amountLabel": self.amountLabel};
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-10-[textLabel]-10-[amountLabel]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Initial TableView before animation:

[image]

TableView during animation (with black right label in the middle of it's journey to the right):

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm battling the same animation issue.

Comment: I know I'm a little late. Did you tried to set frames of that labels before adding them to contentView? Something like this: `CGRect bounds = self.bounds; CGFloat labelWidth = (bounds.size.width - 10 * 3) / 2; self.textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, labelWidth, bounds.size.height)]; self.amountLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10 + labelWidth + 10, 0, labelWidth, bounds.size.height)];`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me in swift. I have added the second label in detailTextLabel and in the attribute inspector for the TableView I had selected style as "Right Detail". I have attached the screenshot of the tableview with attribute inspector.

[image]

[image]

```
 cell.textLabel!.text = arrayLabel[indexPath.row]
 cell.detailTextLabel!.text = cntarray[indexPath.row]
```

Hope it might be helpful to you.